# Location of Chrome autofill data?

Tags: google-chrome, database, auto-form-fill, file-location

I find how to view (browser) the Chrome autofill data. But i can't find the location of the database file. Anyone have the information for this?

Answer (score 2):

#### Where is the Chrome Autofill database stored?

**Windows**:

- `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Data`, or
- `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Chrome Web Data`

**Ubuntu** / **Linux**:

- `~/.config/chromium/Default/Web\ Data`, or
- `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Web\ Data`

**MacOS**:

- `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Web Data`

Answer (score 0):

Some is also on https://takeout.google.com/
but as we see on the "highlighted comment" at
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IzDVOy2y-E&lc=UgzfQhGYHAlJI9jA-194AaABAg , some must be hidden deeper.